# constexpr of pointer to fixed address

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr

I have code like this:

```
constexpr int *p = (int*)0x12345678;
```

but the compiler (rightfully) says:

```
foo.cc:1:20: error: ‘reinterpret_cast’ from integer to pointer
    1 | constexpr int *p = (int*)0x12345678;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there any equivalent code or way to mark this instance of a cast to be acceptable as constexpr?

Note: In the embedded / micro-controller world having memory mapped device registers is really common but because of this one can't use constexpr for any of the code involved with them.

PS: A solution requiring gcc or clang is fine. Doesn't need to be portable.

Comment: "*because of this one can't use constexpr for any of the code involved with them*" What would you do with this pointer that *won't* break compile-time rules? It doesn't point to anything; it's an invalid pointer. At compile-time, the compiler *knows* its an invalid pointer, so dereferencing it will be ill-formed. These kind of low-level manipulations can't be done at compile-time, as they require specific knowledge of and access to the machine in question. Which the compiler doesn't have.

Comment: Not sure what value you'd get out of the fact that the pointer value is a constexpr. Perhaps adding a wrapper that hides the reinterpret-cast would be a suitable option? `class MappedIntAddress {size_t m_address; public: constexpr MappedIntAddress(size_t address) : m_address(address){} operator int() { return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(m_address); } MappedIntAddress& operator=(int value) {*reinterpret_cast<int*>(m_address) = value; return *this; } }; constexpr MappedIntAddress p = 0x12345678;`; This could possibly allow you to add logic to the operators to allow for debugging...

Comment: I can create a struct containing a list of registers, I can return it, do arithmetic on it, use it as template parameter, ... The only thing I can't do is dereference it.

Comment: @fabian That might be a solution (using uintptr_t instead of size_t though for correctness). Have to test this but it should allow everything a constexpr pointer would allow at compile time while the cast-on-use should produce no runtime cost.

Comment: I think this use case is when the `volatile` keyword is actually useful (and the only such purpose I know of).

Comment: @aschepler That's besides the point. (volatile is actually required but where you place it is a matter of taste)

Answer (score 1):

This non-portable method appears to work using g++ 11 and GNU ld, even allowing the pointer to be used as a template argument. (clang++ does not allow it as a template argument.)

A pointer-type template argument must point at a named variable with external linkage, so I introduce a variable for the actual value, and get the linker rather than compiler to provide that variable's symbol name as a specific address.

```
#include <cstdio>

// Provide command-line argument -Wl,--defsym=p_var=0x12345678
extern volatile int p_var;
constexpr volatile int* p = &p_var;
constexpr volatile int* p2 = p+1;
constexpr volatile int* p3 = p2-1;

template <volatile int* P> void print_addr() {
    std::printf("%p\n", const_cast<void*>(static_cast<volatile void*>(P)));
}

// After linking, the code contains constant 0x1234567c and no add instruction.
volatile int* get_p2() { return p2; }

int main() {
    print_addr<p>();
    // print_addr<p2>();  ERROR: invalid template argument
    print_addr<p3>();
}
```

Some of the pointer arithmetic is actually happening at link time, not compile time, but g++ apparently doesn't mind for the purposes of C++ language requirements.

[Try this code on godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A//+Note+the+linker+command-line+argument+-Wl,--defsym%3Dp_var%3D0x12345678%0Aextern+volatile+int+p_var%3B%0Aconstexpr+volatile+int*+p+%3D+%26p_var%3B%0Aconstexpr+volatile+int*+p2+%3D+p%2B1%3B%0Aconstexpr+volatile+int*+p3+%3D+p2-1%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cvolatile+int*+P%3E+void+print_addr()+%7B%0A++++std::printf(%22%25p%5Cn%22,+const_cast%3Cvoid*%3E(static_cast%3Cvolatile+void*%3E(P)))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+After+linking,+the+code+contains+constant+0x1234567c+and+no+add+instruction.%0Avolatile+int*+get_p2()+%7B+return+p2%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++print_addr%3Cp%3E()%3B%0A++++//+print_addr%3Cp2%3E()%3B++ERROR:+invalid+template+argument%0A++++print_addr%3Cp3%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.66479663394111,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wl,--defsym%3Dp_var%3D0x12345678%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.118348694162584,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g112,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wl,--defsym%3Dp_var%3D0x12345678%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:47.33520336605892,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: But it's not actually valid C. There is no compilation unit for p_var. You just fudge it in with linker magic. While it totally works for me it always smells.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where the address is defined in the C source so the code is readable and not hidden away in some linker script.